# DMax function msaccess

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Wanna help

in attached screen shot I want before insert in table SNo should be checked with date if the SNo is added already in the date whNo should be +1 with the last SNo, and if no SNo is adich i entered in form then Sded in the entered date then it shoul start it from 1.. Thanks

Comment: Please include code and data, not screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, as i am new here and didn't know about it. I have no code for this because i am also new in Access.... my requirements are that on the Form when i enter the date it should be checked that if this date has already a SNo then it should extract the last SNo from the date, and if there is no SNo against the entered date then it should starts it from 1.

Comment: OK. Found an example that should get you started.